# Error while querying the now() in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

Iam getting the below error while running the following select query select now();

conversion to class java.time.OffsetDateTime from timestamptz not supported

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and show us the Java code you are using (`resultSet.getObject(..., OffsetDateTime.class);` works for me). And what is the version of the Postgres JDBC driver you are using?

Comment: postgresql-42.2.9.jre6 and the postgres version which iam using is
postgresql-10.11-3-windows-x64

Comment: That driver version is intended for Java **6** and obviously it can't support classes introduced in Java 8. Why are you using a driver for such an outdated Java version? You need to use `postgresql-42.2.9.jar`

Comment: This link of Mapping between Postgres and JAVA date/time:https://tada.github.io/pljava/use/datetime.html might be of some help

Comment: after adding the latest jar postgresql-42.2.9.jar the issue got resolved..thanks for the help